# Global and local PyQt5 style sheet

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

Global sheet:

```
QPushButton {
    border-radius: 20px;    
    font: 57 18pt "Ubuntu Medium";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(166, 0, 0);
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(9, 153, 131);
}

pushButton_4 {
    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 0);
}
```

Local sheet:

```
background-color: rgb(0, 229, 115);
```

I want to create buttons with different colors in the same window, but with the same: hover effect. But when I change the color in the local css table, the global window table for this button is canceled and vice versa.

Comment: Please add code as *text* not images. Then, it's not clear what you've done and what you mean: is the "local button sheet" the *full* stylesheet of the button?

Comment: @musicamante Ok code was uploaded as 'code'. Local button sheet is a full stylesheet of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic stylesheets are normally fine for simple cases, but whenever parent/propagation comes into play, they should be avoided in favor of explicit [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

In your case, the issue is that using the *generic* stylesheet, it overrides *any* other previously set property, as that syntax takes precedence (read more on [conflict resolution](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#conflict-resolution)).

Using the class selector won't be enough, though, as it will completely override any other properties in similar fashion, so the solution is to specify the *opposite* of what you want to use (`:hover`) by *negating* it:

```
QPushButton:!hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 229, 115);
}
```

Note that the following also works, but it's usually better to use selectors in any case (mostly to keep good practice and consistence, so that you don't risk facing unexpected results when trying to do this on a parent widget):

```
:!hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 229, 115);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: @Dzheremi you're welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tickmark on its left.